# JQuery and CSS Hover Function for an Old-School Image Map IE Problems

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, imagemap

I have an image with an image map that I need to overlay with a semi-transparent div and anchor. Since the image and image map vary page to page, the actual code dynamically generates an image map, reusing a single div and anchor for the overlaid link.

You can see a simplified version of the code on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyXSZ/19/). I have had fits getting it to work in both Firefox and IE. As the code is now, it works in both, but if you move the mouse slowly off to the left of the yellow box in IE, the white background from the "highlight" div is left behind. The mouseleave function--as you can tell if you uncomment the alert--is triggered every time, so it appears the problem is with this line:

```
$('#highlight').css('display', 'none');
```

When I change the CSS from the highlight div's anchors to the highlight div itself,I have the lingering div problem in BOTH Firefox and IE. Using the highlight a:hover, it only happens with IE and Firefox works fine.

If I leave the "background-color: white" out of the inline CSS for the highlight box, the code fails in IE; the highlight doesn't show at all.

I've tried using a number of different approaches, including switching the CSS between the a:hover pseudoclass and the highlight div itself, using different functions in JQuery, and none work reliably in IE.

I've taken a look at some of the JQuery plugins like MapHilight, and they cause problems with some of the other code I have to use.

Can anyone see what I'm missing to get this to work reliably in IE as well as other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I basically played with your map coords and came upt with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQCup/)

I always let my maps overlap at the edges using the same value so I don't get a phantom "pixel to nowhere"

Comment: Thanks very much for the effort. I tested your solution and it doesn't leave behind the highlight div in IE; however, I don't think it will work in the actual code where there may only be a small area of an image that is in the map, and rarely are there contiguous areas in a map. Is there some way I can adjust your solution in that case that I'm missing?